# When I click on the like button it doesn't call the method which set to be invoked

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, adapter

When I click on the like button it doesn't call the method which set to be invoked in the adapter, it gives output in logcat "viewpostime pointer 0" and "viewpostime pointer 1". I did similar thing with another adapter and it worked well. don't know why it is not calling the method, the Log.D is working fine in this. all I want is when the button is clicked it performes the function of l1comment() to update the database

my concern is regarding the FavPostButton in onBindViewHolder

below is the code,

```
protected void getComments() {
    Query query = db.collection("posts").document(Post_Key).collection("comments");
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Comments> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Comments>()
            .setQuery(query, Comments.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Comments, CommentsViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CommentsViewHolder commentsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Comments comments) {
            documentId = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(i).getId();

            commentsViewHolder.textViewTitle.setText(comments.getUsername());
            commentsViewHolder.textViewDescription.setText(comments.getComment());

            commentsViewHolder.favPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    l1Comment();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Your CommentID" + documentId);
                }
            });
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CommentsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.comment_list_items, parent, false);

            return new CommentsViewHolder(view);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
    };

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    commentsList.setAdapter(adapter);


}

private void l1Comment() {


    likesRef = db.collection("posts").document(Post_Key).collection("comments").document(documentId);

    likesRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if (documentSnapshot.contains(mUserId)) {
                likesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            if (document.exists()) {
                                if (document.get("l1") != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "You already in Process", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "your field exist");
                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "your field does not exist");
                                    likeChecker = true;
                                    Map<String, Object> commentMap = new HashMap<>();
                                    commentMap.put("l1", likeChecker);
                                    likesRef.update(commentMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "l1 done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }

                                        }
                                    });

                                    //Create the filed
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {

            }

        }
    });
}

public static class CommentsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    TextView textViewTitle;
    TextView textViewDescription;
    TextView textViewPriority;
    Button favPostButton;
    Button commentsbutton;


    public CommentsViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_comment_name);
        textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_comment_content);
        textViewPriority = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_comment_stamp);
        commentsbutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comments_input_button);
        favPostButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_liking);


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check `favPostButton`'s `onClick` event work properly or not? A small suggestion is, send `documentId` as parameter of `l1Comment()`.

Comment: yes the onclick is working fine, and documenId as parameter didn't worked

Comment: Did you debug your code using break pointer? If you didn't then try to find out the line where your code is not working. Maybe you are missing something silly.

Comment: When Debugged it is saying "Skipped 2313 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: Run `likesRef.update(commentMap)` operation in different thread (not in main thread).

Comment: I am a newbie, can you give me some reference for the same

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and see the result in the firebase dashboard.

```
private void l1Comment() {
    likesRef = db.collection("posts").document(Post_Key).collection("comments").document(documentId);
    likesRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (documentSnapshot.contains(mUserId)) {
                likesRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            if (document.exists()) {
                                if (document.get("l1") != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "You already in Process", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "your field exist");
                                } else {
                                    new Thread("update_thread"){
                                        public void run(){
                                            Log.d(TAG, "your field does not exist");
                                            likeChecker = true;
                                            Map<String, Object> commentMap = new HashMap<>();
                                            commentMap.put("l1", likeChecker);
                                            likesRef.update(commentMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(CommentActivity.this, "l1 done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    } else {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                            //Create the filed
                                        }
                                    }.start();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
}
```